# How to concatenate two columns values from another table in the insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Comment` and I need to insert the values to the table `Comment` from another table `ProComment` as shown here:

```
INSERT INTO Comment (id, insertdate, commenttext, reviewdate) 
    VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 'This is the new review period from ', GETDATE())
```

But I want to get the `reviewstartdate` and `reviewenddate` from `ProComment` and need to append with `commenttext` in the `Comment` table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Comment (id, insertdate, commenttext, reviewdate) 
    VALUES (1, GETDATE(),
        'This is the new review period from ' + (SELECT reviewstartdate, 'to ', reviewenddate FROM ProComment WHERE id = 1), 
        GETDATE())
```

Expected results will be "This is the new review period from 2018-05-05 to 2019-05-05" on the comment section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get rid of the [*Table Value Constructor* `values`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and put a regular select statement including [`CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function or `+` operator to concatenate the strings :

```
insert into Comment( id, insertdate, commenttext, reviewdate) 
select 1, getdate(),
       concat('This is the new review period from ', reviewstartdate,' to ',reviewenddate), 
       getdate()
  from ProComment 
 where id = 1
```